# Readonly input without changing mouse icon / css?

Tags: html

```
echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' . $server->address . ":" . $server->connection_port . '">';
```

Is there any way to active readonly mode for this input but without changing it's css or mouse icon on hover of that input area?

Comment: Please give a better example of your requirements. For example, if you're asking about making an element readonly then the value of it is irrelevant to the problem as is the PHP you're using to output the HTML. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery `attr()` `method` you can add `readonly attribute` as below, this is how you can add, still add your remaining code to get better output.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".form-control").attr('readonly','true');
});
```

```css
.form-control:hover{
  background:blue;
  transition:1s ease;
  outline:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Name" class="form-control">
```

Comment: @Nikola the above code targets all, to target only one, you have to replace above input by class or id which you have included in input tag.

Comment: @Nikola Post full code and proper explanation of error, you will get proper output and if above code works do accept or up-vote.